# Как применить функцию к набору датасетов pandas используя все ядра машины?

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность, pandas

Есть долговыполняемая функция `func`, которую нужно применить к набору датасетов `pandas` (лежат в словаре) используя все ядра машины.

Сейчас это делается последовательно через цикл. Грузит машину на 5%, считает медленно:

```
for name in city_names:
    func(DB[name])
```

Делала через потоки:

```
London = Thread(target=func, args=(DB['London']))
Paris = Thread(target=func, args=(DB['Paris']))

London.start()
Paris.start()

London.join()
Paris.join()
```

Выдает предупреждение:

> Exception in thread Thread-

Также приходится вручную каждому городу назначать поток, а это не удобно, т.к. меняются списки городов для рассчетов.

Как применить функцию к набору датасетов pandas используя все ядра машины?

Comment: https://github.com/modin-project/modin - так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По совету @strawdog попробовала использовать `modin`

```
import modin.pandas as pd
```

Скорость работы с датасетами возросла в среднем 2 раза в моем случае. Отдельные функции, например `pd.read_csv` ускорились в 4 раза!

Для всего этого требуется только модификация импорта в одну строку кода.
[Руководство](https://modin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started/quickstart.html)